# Rails 3 string contains HTML code need to loop through the code in string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am working on the rails 3 application where i need to pass the html code in to the string variable and pass it to the web services as parameter.

I have the following code with the loop inside but since it is declare in to the string it is not working  with the <%%> and #{} tag

```
      @emaildata = "<H3>FLOOR VIEW ACTION REQUEST</H3>
      <table border='0' cellspacing='4'>
        <tr>
          <td>Submitted On:</td>
          <td align='left'><strong>#{Date.today}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Originator: </td>
          <td align='left'><strong>#{session[:user_name]}</strong></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <table border=0 width=100%>
                  <tr bgcolor='##006699'>
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>ACTION CODE</strong></font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>PART<BR />NUMBER</strong></font></td> 
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>LOCATION</strong></font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>BIN QTY</strong></font></td> 
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>PACK QTY</strong></font></td> 
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>UM</strong></font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>SCAN CODE</strong></font></td>
                    <td align='center'><font color='##FFFFFF'><strong>REASON / COMMENTS</strong></font></td> 
                  </tr>


                <% (1..PartNoListInEmail.length).each_index do |i|%>
                  <tr bgcolor='##E0E5E5'>
                    <td align='center'>#{@ActionCodeListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@PartNoListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@SendToListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@OrderQtyListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@PackQtyListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@UMListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@ScancodeListInEmail[i]}</td>
                    <td align='center'>#{@reasonForActionIn[i]}</td>
                  </tr> 
               <%end%>
    </table>"
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 2):

Save your html as partial as a `html.erb`

```
@emaildata = "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>'some_partial_name', :locals => {:PartNoListInEmail => @PartNoListInEmail}).html_safe %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

For combining strings with HTML, you want to use a template system like Erb or Haml. If you don't intend to immediately render the template back to a browser, you can still use Erb to do this by calling Erb directly, having it parse the HTML string and variables and return the result as a string.

Once you go down this road, be extra careful of user provided content and escape anything untrustworthy. When you render erb templates normally in rails, rails does a fair amount of work for you to avoid these sorts of problems, but once you do something like what your example showed, or if you use Erb directly to parse it, you no longer benefit from Rails' safety checks, and therefore will need to put in your own checks.